# Chrome Developer Console Can't Run JS Loops

Tags: google-chrome, console, syntax, javascript

In the chrome console, I can't run any loops. Why is this?

For example, the following will give a syntax error of "Expected '('"

```
for each (var item in [1, 2, 3]) alert(item)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`each` isn't a Javascript keyword. See [the W3Schools page on Javascript's `for` statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp) for reference.

Try the following:

```
for ( var item in [1,2,3] ) alert(item)
```

Comment: I'm running chrome and tested this.  It works.  Also, I'd never opened Chrome's js console.  Holy crap this thing is firebug built into the browser...

Answer (score 2):

It's been a long time since the question is posted. I'm a new user and just found out one more way or a better way to do it.

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach( el => alert(el))
```

Hope this also may help someone.